# select records having all null values in a specific temporal window

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table:

```
CODE | INSTANT | VAL
```

inside of a temporal window, based on the INSTANT column value, VAL can be null or not null.
So you could have something like this:

```
'A',2015-06-29 08:00:01,null
'A',2015-06-29 08:30:01,5
'A',2015-06-29 09:00:00,null
'B',2015-06-29 08:00:01,null
'B',2015-06-29 08:30:01,null
'B',2015-06-29 09:00:00,null
```

Now, given the temporal window:

```
2015-06-29 08:00:00 <--> 2015-06-29 09:00:00
```

I'd like to get the code of records which are **ALL** null in that temporal window. In this example the answer is just "B", as records with code "A" have at least one entry, 5, which is not null into specified temporal window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the codes that are all `NULL` for the records within a certain range of values.  If so, then you can use aggregation and a `having` clause, something like this:

```
select t.code
from table t
where t.instant >= WINDOW_START and
      t.instant <= WINDOW_END
group by t.code
having max(val) is null;
```

And equivalent `having` clause is:

```
having count(val) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks, really a clean query and seems to have acceptable performances as well.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you just a single record per code that does not have a VAL for the given date range

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CODE
FROM
    table1 t1
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS ( SELECT
                    1
                 FROM
                    table1 t2
                 WHERE
                    t1.CODE = t2.CODE               
                    AND t2.VAL IS NOT NULL
                    AND INSTANT BETWEEN '2015-06-29 09:00:00'
                                AND     '2015-06-29 09:00:00' )
```